# Excel Dynamic Drop Down List

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables that get dynamically created from a database query; the first table is the source of the drop-down list, and the second is the table that I will apply the drop-down list via data validation. First table:

[image]

and the second table:

[image]

What I need, ideally through just Excel formulas, is an intelligently designed drop-down that shows only the dimension values associated to the dimension in question.

So in cells B3:B10, the drop-downs would show a,b,c.  In cells C3:C10, the drop-downs would show 1,2,3. In cells D3:D10, the drop-downs would show x,y,z. Etc, etc.

I need this to be dynamic in the sense that a week from now my DB query may return a fourth dimension that would need to follow the same approach.

Not sure if this is even possible without writing some VBA, but I figure I'd see if anybody has any creative ideas. Cheers!

Comment: That is possible and not so complex. I have steps to do that, but due to some urgent work, I could not answer now. I will answer later.

Comment: Thanks -- much appreciated!

Comment: It is possible but can be complex depending on the flexibility you need. Will the categories in the first table always be together? Can they be retrieved sorted? Are the columns of the second table to be created dynamically? Note that you'll need some technical columns to be added to the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Name Manager` and `=INDIRECT()` formula to achieve that. 
First download the sample file.
[Sample File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByUqUZQzUv2tcEw5OWs0cHNfMnM/view?usp=sharing)

See this tip (By me). It will help you to see screenshots step by step. [Link is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByUqUZQzUv2tSmhlWTZzS09MdmM/view?usp=sharing)

Now in-case of your data you have to use some formula to filter data automatically when new data come. So that new data can organize for dynamic combo boxes. I can also do that for you if you are not able to do that. Then share your sample workbook with me.

Comment: Sorry for late answering. It was weekend here.

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible, but not simple. There are a several ways to implement this, depending on your requirements, how dynamic it needs to be, and the expected structure of the data (as I mentioned in a comment).

I will give one possible solution, that is mostly dynamic, and is the simplest to explain. You can use a similar logic to make it all dynamic.

This solution will retrieve the data from table #1 according to the dimension name, assuming it is not sorted, and return the values in the order they are given in the table.

*For some of the ranges I create names for simplicity, and some are mandatory. In order to follow the formulas logic you need the named ranges I use.*

1. Create named ranges for table #1: (Either by using the Name Box or using the Name Manager Ctrl+F3):

   - For the data in the column Dimension: **DimName** =B3:B11
   - For the column Dimenstion Value: **DimValue** =C3:C11
2. Create dimension values lists in a new sheet:

   - Put the dimension name in B2 `="Customer"`. (The available dimension names can be created dynamically as well, but I'm skipping this part for simplisity).
   - B3 (**array formula** - Ctrl+Shift+Enter) `=IFERROR(INDEX(DimVal,SMALL(IF(DimName=B$2,ROW(DimName)-ROW(INDEX(DimName,1))+1),ROWS(B$3:B3)),1),"")`. This formula returns the k-th value for the "Customer" dimension.
   - Copy B3 down to as many rows you think you'll need. Let's say B4:B10, so B3:B10 will have the array formula. The first cells will have the available values and the remaining cells will be empty because of the IFERROR function.
   - In B1 we will count the available values using the formula `=SUMPRODUCT(--(B3:B10<>"")`.
   - Do the same for "Product" and "Geography" in columns C and D.
3. Create dynamic named ranges for the lists: (using the Name Manager Ctrl+F3)

   - For the lists' data **DimLists** =B3:D10.
   - For the lists' headers **DimListHeaders** =B2:D2.
   - For the lists' counts **DimListCounts** =B1:D1.
   - *These names are mandatory for the data validation to work in another sheet.
4. Set table #2 data validation list sources:

   - Select B3:B10 in table #2.
   - Go to Data > Data Validation, and select Allow: **List**.
   - Put the following formula in the source: `=OFFSET(INDEX(DimLists,,MATCH(B$2,DimListHeaders,0)),,,INDEX(DimListCount,,MATCH(B$2,DimListHeaders,0)))`. This formula finds the correct list in **DimLists** according to the column header in table #2, and also sets the returned range height according to the list count.

Hope this helps.